# some of execution failed due to unable connect any specific mysql hosts vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have look around regarding this issues. Recently i faced issues so called unable to conenct any specific mysql server in vb.net. Means in middle of execution of MYSQL, some of execution might interrupted and missing out. So let say i execute 3 mysql operation update, insert and delete, so in middle of execution of this 3 operation, suddenly it pop out "unable to connect any specific  mysql HOSTS" and execution for update or insert might missed out. Sometime some columns of execution is missing out and make the execuation incomplete..I tried to change the connection timeout to longger time for 90sec, but still doesnt help. Any suggestion?

You mean instead of doing this

```
sqlQuery="Update"
executeQuery(sqlQuery, Connection2)

sqlQuery="Update"
executeQuery(sqlQuery, Connection2)

sqlQuery="Insert"
executeQuery(sqlQuery, Connection2)
```

better doing this

```
sqlQuery="Update"
sqlQuery="Update"
sqlQuery="Insert"
executeQuery(sqlQuery, Connection2)
```

Comment: If you need to perform multiple operations then why are you connecting more than once? You should connect, perform all operations, then disconnect. If all operations must be performed or not as a unit then use a transaction. That's exactly what they exist for.

Comment: @jmcilhinney look at my post i update it. did you mean by that?

Comment: How could that second code snippet work? `sqlQuery` can't contain three values when you call `executeQuery`. I don't know how your code is designed but what I mean is create a connection, open it, begin a transaction, execute each SQL statement that you need to execute, commit or rollback the transaction, close the connection.

Comment: If you're using the same connection string each time and it is working sometimes and failing others then I can only conclude that there is a network issue. Even if you connect once, if the connection drops out part-way through then you'll still fail to complete all the operations. The transaction should ensure that you don't end up with partial changes to the database.

Comment: the first snippet is my code looks like. i create the conenction, open, dispose and close using executeQuery function. im using the same connection instead. Does the accessing huge queries on the database can cause this issues?